# Can not read text file with Qt 5

Tags: c++, qt

I wrote a simple code to open plain text file with Qt 5's QFile as seen below;

```
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>
using std::endl;
using std::cout;

#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QFile>
#include <QIODevice>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QFile plainFile("plain.txt");

    if(plainFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
    {
        cout << "File opened successfull" << endl;
        plainFile.close();
    }
    else{
        cout << "could not open file." << endl;
    }
    return a.exec();
}
```

The output when compiled and run is "could not open file".
What am I do wrong?

Comment: Well, is there a plain.txt in the working directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably because `plain.txt` does not exist in the current working directory or in the PATH. Make sure the file is in the working directory or pass the absolute path to `QFile`.

Also see what [`QFile::exists`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qfile.html#exists-2) returns.

Comment: plain.txt exists int he same working directory, but as you suggested, passing the absolute path to QFile does work! Thanks.

Comment: So the file _does not_ exist in the working directory. If you want to find out what the working directory really is, try this: `qDebug() << QFileInfo("plain.txt").absoluteFilePath();`

Comment: You can also figure out the (startup) path from the project options in QtCreator or Visual Studio

Comment: QDir::currentPath/current also return the current working directory http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/qdir.html#currentPath

Comment: Had the same issue. Printing the actual working directory shows that its NOT  the file in which the source code is compiling but rather its adjacent debug file. How the heck did it decide that and how do I change it?

Answer (score 0):

Wouter Huysentruit is right.

Remember, that, by default, when you running application from QtCreator working directory is, for example, `C:\Projects\build-Test-Desktop_Qt_5_1_0_MinGW_32bit-Debug`. But your `.exe` file lay in `C:\Projects\build-Test-Desktop_Qt_5_1_0_MinGW_32bit-Debug\Debug`.

When you run your `.exe` directly, then working directory will be that folder, where this file is layed now.

So, you can:

1.Pass absolute path.

2.Put file in **current** working directory (I suppose that it is best solution).

3.Just change relative path: `QFile plainFile("debug/plain.txt");`